# Upgrading GCC from 4.8 to 4.9

Tags: gcc, webserver, cmake, helpfile

I am trying to install the TrinityCore on my server. When upgrading the `GCC` to use `CMake` I ran into a problem:

Here is the response I got:

```
gcc-4.9 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@sd-25884:/home/wow/TrinityCore/build# cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/wow/server -DCONF_DIR=/home/wow/server/etc -DTOOLS=1 -DWITH_WARNINGS=1
-- Detected 64-bit platform
-- UNIX: Using default library directory
-- UNIX: Configuring uninstall target
-- UNIX: Created uninstall target
-- UNIX: Detected compiler: /usr/bin/cc
CMake Error at cmake/compiler/gcc/settings.cmake:7 (message):
  GCC: TrinityCore requires version 4.9.0 to build but found 4.8.4
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/platform/unix/settings.cmake:29 (include)
  cmake/macros/CheckPlatform.cmake:13 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:58 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/wow/TrinityCore/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
root@sd-25884:/home/wow/TrinityCore/build#
```

Answer (score 4):

CMake uses several [variables](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) to set the default compiler.  You are mostly interested in setting `CC` variable to override default C compiler.  In your case that would be:

```
CC=gcc-4.9 cmake ../ -
```

You might need to `apt-get install g++-4.9` if the TrinityCore is written in C++, and that would be:

```
CXX=g++-4.9 cmake ../ -
```